# Java,JVM and OS and swap

Tags: java, jvm, solaris

I wonder if i start a java virtual machine with:

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC 
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m -XX:-BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs
```

So I start the server with -Xms equal to -Xmx I  the java OS process will "hold" the memory from the OS for good ? So this JVM will have 2GB for it and if the OS has it then it will allow the process to start otherwise no.

Is there a possibility that after the JVM start with 2GB to use the swap memory of the os ?

(so if it starts initially without using the swap memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will use about 2400 MB of virtual memory on start up.  It never gives back the virtual memory.  It can give back the main memory but rarely does.

> Is there a possibility that after the JVM start with 2GB to use the swap memory of the os ?

Technical yes, but in practice this is a very bad idea.  The GC when it is performed assumes it has random access to all the memory.  If you JVM starts to swap it can halt for long periods of time (many minutes) and even hang the machine.

Given you can buy 32 GB for about $200, it's usually simpler to buy enough memory for your needs.

Comment: That is what happens actually "starts to swap it can halt for long periods of time" but i do not understand why cause the OS, shows that there is enough...so if JVM will use 2GB and it is 'his' when it might use the swap ?

Comment: @Cris The virtual memory is virtual for the process because the OS can do (almost always) what it deems necessary with it. If another process starts and asks for enough memory to go above the physical memory of the computer, the OS will have to swap some memory pages, and will usually do so for the longer running process.

Comment: but using xms = xmx will not 'tell' to the os : i need at least this xms memory and max xmx so i inform you of that.the os allocates at least xms for the java process ? so ...you say later because i start some other process on the same machine it might get the memory from the jvm and the jvm will use the swap ?

Comment: @Cris Yes, it's the same for any process, the JVM is not a special case for the OS. Virtual memory would not exist if the OS was not allowed to swap some pages from an existing process to satisfy the request of another. The only pages that can be swapped are those that have been allocated.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with the JVM is pure on the OS level...however in order for the JVM to start using the swap the OS needs another process that will 'steal' the memory ,as i uderstood from the long running JVM process..if the JVM is the only process on that machine would be hard to happen i guess (by only i mean an empty solaris zone  weblogic server running)

Comment: @Cris I'm not familiar with the Solaris Zones (I just skimmed though the Wikipedia article), apparently they're not exactly like VMs found nowadays as they run on a single kernel, but I don't see why they wouldn't run cron, for example, which could use some memory from time to time. Trying to fit exactly in the supposedly available memory is bound to fall on corner cases, and with a JVM it can be fatal (from the users' point of vue) as Peter noted.

Comment: The `-ms` or `-Xms` option only specifies up to this point it makes little attempt to reclaim memory.  A Hello World program will not use 2 GB no matter which you set Xms to be.  The JVM may even do some collections before reaching the "minimum" heap size.

Comment: The OS pages out on a least recently used basis.  First it pages out a) clean disk cached data b) dirty disk data i.e. unsaved writes c) program memory.  It has two "clocks" which pass over the memory pages. One clock hand marks a page as untouched recently and another hand looks for pages which haven't need touched.  The OS tries to maintain a free pool and the faster memory is used, the faster the hands move trying to find pages which haven't been used recently.  The JVM has no involvement or knowledge of this process.